# vsftpd on ubuntu saucy - "OOPS: Child died"

Tags: ubuntu, security, ftp, vsftpd

I have installed vsftpd with `apt-get install vsftpd` on my freshly deployed ubuntu saucy amd64 linode.

vsftpd starts but when I connect to it from an ftp client, even from localhost, I get this error: `OOPS: child died`

`syslog` and `kern.log` show this:

```
Jan 28 14:00:37 gravy kernel: type=1326 audit(1390917637.827:67): auid=4294967295 uid=65534 gid=65534 ses=4294967295 pid=27687 comm="vsftpd" sig=31 syscall=96 compat=0 ip=0x7fff48196968 code=0x0
```

The default configuration options in `/etc/vsftpd.conf` are:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

I though it might be something to do with pam or SSL so I commented out those last 3 lines and restarted but still get the same problem.

There is nothing in `/var/log/vsftpd.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in `vsftpd` that affected 64-bit machines, here's the [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=845980) - it looks fixed on Red Hat's distributions but it's not yet fixed on some other distributions.

As a workaround, you may add `seccomp_sandbox=NO` to its configuration file but that will disable a sandboxing feature (not sure about what it does exactly, but if security is your priority you shouldn't use FTP anyway).

```
echo "seccomp_sandbox=NO" >> /etc/vsftpd.conf
```